# Body of emails with ical-event is not shown

Tags: email, smtp, html-email, icalendar, email-client

I am sending an HTML email with an ical invitation attached.

I'm facing the issue that many mail-clients do not show the body of the mail properly.

- Thunderbird shows neither the plain-text nor html e-mail body, only the raw invitation
- Outlook 2013 seems to show the html-body but totally messed up. Only the raw text contained within the html-mail is shown. CSS seems to be ignored

This issue occurs only if the ical-attachment is present. If I send the same mail without the ical attachment, everything works fine.

Is there maybe some kind of header that tells mail-clients to also show the mail-body in addition to the ical-invitation or what else could I be missing?

```
Date: Thu, 26 Aug 2021 08:47:10 +0200 (CEST)
From: John Doe <john@doe.com>
To: Max Mustermann <max@mustermann.de>
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Best=C3=A4tigung_Ihres_Termins_am_18.08.2020?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
    boundary="----=_Part_6_1140395501.1629960429000"

------=_Part_6_1140395501.1629960429000
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<... my plain text mail ...>

------=_Part_6_1140395501.1629960429000
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!doctype html>
<... my HTML email ...>

------=_Part_6_1140395501.1629960429000
Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=UTF-8; method=REQUEST
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//My Company//My App//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20210826T064710Z
UID:38c15e72-12cf-44d1-97ea-a5a753f4b724
SUMMARY:Your Appointment
DESCRIPTION:Passwort: secure123\nhttps://example.com/meeting
LOCATION:Online-Meeting
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20200818T153000
ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=FALSE;CN=John Doe;EMAIL=john@doe.com:mailto:john@doe.com
ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=FALSE;CN=Max Mustermann;EMAIL=max@mustermann.de:mailto:max@mustermann.de
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

------=_Part_6_1140395501.1629960429000--
```

Comment: Probably don't put a genuine human's address in your examples; spammers will pick it up and start sending unwanted messages to the recipients. The domain `example.com` exists for the explicit purpose of being used in examples.

Comment: I thought your MIME structure looked wonky, but it seems that Outlook sends calendar events with exactly this structure, so I have deleted my (non-) answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when sending ical Attachements from Rails and trying to check the resulting mails with MailCatcher.

The problem is the `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit` (typically used for binary files) but your attachment is more like plain text.

Try to use `quoted-printable` instead, like in this example:

```
----==_mimepart_612e500330e6c_dd52137407244b
Content-Type: text/calendar;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename=A-1105.ics
Content-ID: <612e500337894_dd521374072738@Nielss-MBP.localdomain.mail>

BEGIN:VCALENDAR=0D
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN=0D
PRODID:-//Foxtag//DE=0D
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Amsterdam=0D
VERSION:2.0=0D
METHOD:PUBLISH=0D
BEGIN:VEVENT=0D
...
```

In Rails you can set the encoding when adding attachments like this:

```
attachments['mycalendar.ics'] = {
    mime_type: "text/calendar",
    encoding: "quoted-printable",
    content: @ical_content_as_string
}
```

Comment: This seems like a red herring. If the calendar part doesn't contain any non-ASCII characters or lines longer than 990 characters or so, `7bit` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Binary files would use `Content-transfer-encoding: base64` or (occasionally) `Content-transfer-encoding: binary` or `8bit`.  The `7bit` designation is specifically for US-ASCII text with short lines.

Comment: @tripleee I can only tell that switching to `quoted-printable`solved a similar problem for me when adding content from a ruby string (in my case utf-8, if not enforced to something else). I think it's rather common to have non-ascii characters in the summary, description or location of an ical event, so enforcing ascii seems not desirable to me ... my suggestion to @Aki is to just give it a short try, and have a look if the behavior changes or not.

Comment: @tripleee maybe my "The problem is..." should be more like "You're free to use other encodings ..." ;)

Comment: If you had UTF-8 then `7bit` is incorrect, and you should encode it e.g. as `quoted-printable`, yes. The OP's example data is pure ASCII, but if it's not properly representative, this could be useful, of course.